# Why are keys immutable in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

Apologies for the fairly naive question, but I believe my own answer to be naive. I think keys (in HashTables) are immutable because we wouldn't want to somehow accidentally alter a key and therefore mess with the sorting of the HashTable. Is this a correct explanation? If so, how can it be more correct?

Answer (score 5):

During the `HashTable.put` the key is hashed and it an its value are stored in one of a number of buckets (which are lists of key value pairs) based on the hash, for example something like:

```
bucket[key.hashcode() % numberOfBuckets].add(key, value)
```

If the key's `hashcode` changes after insertion it could then be in the wrong bucket and you would then not be able to find it and the hashtable would incorrectly return `null` on any `get` for that key.

Aside: Understanding the inner workings of a hashtable helps you understand the importance of a good quality `hashcode` function for your keys. As a poor hashcode function could result in a poor distribution of keys in buckets. And as buckets are just lists, this results in a lot of linear searches which greatly reduces the effectiveness of the hashtable. e.g. this terrible hashcode function puts everything in one bucket, so it's effectively just one list.

```
public int hashcode { return 42; /*terrible hashcode example, don't use!*/ }
```

This is also one reason why prime numbers appear in good hashcode functions, e.g.:

```
public int hashcode {
    int hash = field1.hashcode();
    hash = hash*31 + field2.hashcode(); //note the prime 31
    hash = hash*31 + field3.hashcode();
    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is correct, but not its details.

Keys in a HashTable need not be immutable, it's the result of a call to their `hashCode()` (and `equals`) method that needs to stay *immutable* and *consistent* (for the hash table to behave predictably, that is).

From a high-level point of view, it's because of the way hash tables work : when a (`key`, `value`) pair is inserted, the `key`'s hashCode is used internally to figure out a "bucket" where the value will be put. And when the `value` is retrieved by `key`, the `hashCode` is computed once more, to find the bucket back.

Now if at any point in time between the insertion and the retreival, the result of calling `hashCode` changes, the "lookup bucket" will be different than the "insertion" bucket, and things will not behave predictably.

To sum up, given a Key object that looks like this (two internal Strings compose the objet, but only one, `partOfHashCode` is taken into account in hashCode / equals) :

```
public static class Key {
  private String partOfHashCode;
  private String notPartOfHashCode;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((partOfHashCode == null) ? 0 : partOfHashCode.hashCode());
    return result;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Key other = (Key) obj;
    if (partOfHashCode == null) {
      if (other.partOfHashCode != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!partOfHashCode.equals(other.partOfHashCode))
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

The it is fine to use it this way :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<Key, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
Key key = new Key();
key.partOfHashCode = "myHash";

myMap.put(key, "value");

key.notPartOfHashCode = "mutation of the key, but not of its hash/equals definition";

System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
}
```

(This logs the "value" object in the console).

But it is NOT fine to use it this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Map<Key, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
  Key key = new Key();
  key.partOfHashCode = "myHash";

  myMap.put(key, "value");

  key.partOfHashCode = "mutation of the hashCode of the key";

  System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
}
```

(This last example could log "null" in the console).

For more on this subject, you should read also on hashCode / equals consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent guarantee in Java that `HashTable`-keys are immutable. It is not even guaranteed that their `hashcode` remains the same. But if you add keys that have a mutable `hashCode` you are in trouble. Assume you are inserting a key with a `hashCode` of 1. Then it is inserted in a hash-bucket corresponding to 1. Then alter the object to have a `hashCode` of 2 and call `hashMap.get(key)`. While the object is still in the `hashTable` the system will look in the bucket corresponding to 2, but won't find it there. You won't even be able to `remove` the entry since it won't be found.

tl;dr For your application to work properly `HashTable`-keys need to have immutable `hashcode`s, but you have to take care of that fact for yourself.